# jquery datatable traverse TR to see id exists before add

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add row using row.add() with jquery datatable.

When this event is fired, i want to traverse the entire TR and compare with data-productID attribute and if productID already exists in one of row I want to stop this.

When this event is fired,  i have productID. What's the easiest way to traverse tr tag in the datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`rows().nodes`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()) or [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API methods.

```
var exists = $('#example').DataTable().rows().nodes().to$().is('tr[data-productID="7"]');
```

or

```
var exists = $('#example').DataTable().$('tr[data-productID="7"]').length;
```